# How to selectively implement only one part of the interface

Tags: c#, oop, architecture, repository-pattern

I am new on repository pattern and try to understand how it implement.For example Lets say I have one class and 2 interface something like this.
and want to implement some certain method ,not all.(on UserRepository).

How can I achive this.

```
public interface IRepository<T>
    {
        #region operations

        List<T>  GetAll();
        void Update(T user);
        void Delete(T user);
        void Add(T user);
        T FindById(int id);
       #endregion

        #region operations async

        List<T> GetAllAsync();
        void UpdateAsync(T user);
        void DeleteAsync(T user);
        void AddAsync(T user);
        T FindByIdAsync(int id);

        #endregion

    }
```

IUserRepository

```
 interface IUserRepository
    {
        int GetUserCount();
        int GetUserType();
        int GetUserPaged();
        int GetUserStars();
    }
```

UserRepository

```
public class UserRepository:IRepository<User>,IUserRepository
{
    public List<User> GetAllAsync()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

   public int GetUserCount()
   {

       return 1;
   }
}
```

Should I have create new Interface again which contains this 2 method? or Is there any better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot selectively choose which parts of the interface to implement. Your only option is to split those methods into stand alone interfaces, but keep in mind you can still inherit interfaces when that makes sense, for example:

```
public interface IReadRepository<T>
{
    T Get(int id);
}

public interface IWriteRepository<T> : IReadRepository<T>
{
    void Add(T entity);
}
```

This way for example, your class can implement only IReadRepository, hence needing to implement only one of the methods.

**EDIT:**

You could also **implement the interfaces explicitly**, and then choose which methods to make publicly available; however I suspect you don't actually want to really implement all the methods from the interface (the real implementations I measn), which if you make them throwing something like NotImplementedException will **violate the Liskov Substitution Principle**...

Comment: what if I use abstract  class instead of the Interface both  IRepository<T> and IUserRepository and override the only the method I want to use.does it out of the basic rules of the implementation of repository pattern

Comment: anyway forget it,my suggestion seems to not make sense

Comment: I am prety  new on OOP .I cheched the lsp. and understand what u trying to say.Thank u